# Extracting a specific column from excel using python Jupyter

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need to extract the data from a certain column in an excel file? How would I do it?

This what I have so far. I have already opened the file successfully and I have the readlines() already.

```py
lines = f.readlines()

f1 = "".join("f")

f2 = f1.split("\t")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using Pandas, it's easier:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df.name_of_column_you_want
```

Comment: Would it work on jupyter as well?

Comment: Sure. It will work.

Comment: How would I change the code from Pandas into jupyter?

Comment: what would change?